# How to separate JaVers implementation in a shared environment?

Tags: java, javers

I am working in an environment consisting between 10-20 teams. Each team has their own set of database tables within a single database schema. All teams are using Java Spring Boot applications with JaVers. I have been tasked to implement some auditing framework for our application. Although we won't be in this environment for long, we are trying to move to AWS instead; the other 19 teams will remain. I need to implement the auditing framework in a way that is easily portable and I don't want to split the data within these shared tables and risk corrupting the data during the migration.

Is there anyway I can use my own JaVers tables instead of the common 4 created by the framework? Instead of jv_table I would want something like my_jv_table.

```
 // Shared 

 jv_commit
 jv_snapshot
 jv_global_id
 jv_cdo_class

 // Separate

 my_jv_commit
 my_jv_snapshot
 my_jv_global_id
 my_jv_cdo_class
```

Then I can easily port only my tables during the migration efforts without worrying about impacting somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change Javers' table names but why not use database schema to separate domains? Schema name is configurable.

Comment: Shoot. The schema name in the database is not something I can control. I would need to get approval from a bunch of managers and then my DBA would need to make the change. It's kind of a big change that I know my leadership won't agree to as they are trying to get all teams using the same platform and to reuse tables and code across the organization. Thanks anyways. I'll use JaVers @TypeName to prefix all my tables so I can select my data from the JV tables with the prefix.